# find length of chord in circle

Tags: geometry

I need a  short way to solve  following problem:

> Suppose that length of chord $AB=5\operatorname{cm}$,$AC=7\operatorname{cm}$ and $BC=8\operatorname{cm}$, we know that $D$ is midpoint of arc  $BC$ and chord   $AD$ divides $BC$ into  two equal parts (let intersection point be $K$) so $BK=KC=4$,  we are  going to find $AK$ and $KD$.

[image: Problem illustration]

First of all I know  characters of chords intersection , which means that $AK\cdot KD=BK \cdot KC$, sure we can find by cosine theorem  $AK$(we know all length,we can find any angle and then repeat usage of cosine)but because $D$ is midpoint of arc  $BC$ and also  $AD$ is median, I doubt that  AD is the  bisector, diameter or something like that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be nice in problems like this to draw a diagram.  Even a paint program will make one good enough for the purpose.

Comment: sorry for my bad pointing,but is is like this

Comment: no 25+49!=64,no diameter

Comment: @SalechAlhasov:  $5^2+7^2=25+49=74 \ne 8^2$

Comment: but actually cosine theorem does not work here,i did not get correct answer  ,why i can not see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get consistency with the cosine theorem.  $7^2=8^2+5^2-2\cdot 8 \cdot 5 \cos B$ leads to $\cos B= \frac 12$ and $AK=\sqrt {21}$.  Similarly $\cos C=\frac {88}{112}$ and again $AK=\sqrt {21}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For a double check that $AD \neq$ radius, the [circumradius](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumradius.html) of $ABC$ is $r =\dfrac{7}{\sqrt{3}}.$ You probably made a mistake in calculations using cosine.

1. The sides of $ABC$ are $5,7,8.$ So the median [(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_%28geometry%29) $AK$ is $\sqrt{21}.$
2. Now that you have $KD,$ use the the equation in your question.